# How do I append dynamic text to image using rmagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm building a rails app where a user can type in six words about themselves and upload an image. I want to append those six words to the image.

I know how to get text append to work using "static" text, but I don't know how to link the text field to the form the users fill out when they type in their six words.

Right now, 'Text' is static and whatever I put.

I wonder why the following doesn't work?

```
process :textify => <%= @user.sixwords %>
```

Here is what I have:

```
process :textify => 'Text'

  def textify(phrase)
    manipulate! do |img|
    img = img.sepiatone

  title = Magick::Draw.new

  title.annotate(img, 0,0,0,40, phrase) {
    self.font_family = 'Helvetica'
    self.fill = 'white'
    self.pointsize = 32  
  }

  img = img.write('newimg.gif')
 end
end
```

Thanks for helping me become a little less of a n00b! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a friend.

This is all that I needed to change:

```
title.annotate(img, 0,0,0,40, model.name) {
    self.font_family = 'Helvetica'
    self.fill = 'white'
    self.pointsize = 32  
  }
```

This works because Carrierwave uses `model` as the variable that points to whatever instance object the uploader is attached to. In my model, `name` was the name of the form field that took the user text input.

For other use cases you'd just take `model.field_name` where you put whatever name you give to your `field_name`.

My friend wrote it like this to explain it to me. I'm pasting it here in case it can help others.

> The 'process' method in ImageUploader is a static class method which
>   only gets called once when the file is loaded into memory and
>   interpreted by ruby.  It's basically just internally keeping track of
>   which processing methods should be called later on for every instance
>   of ImageUploader.  The textify method is the instance method that gets
>   called on each ImageUploader object instance that gets created.  The
>   'mount_uploader' class method that you call in your Athlete model is
>   doing some ruby magic to instantiate the ImageUploader instance and
>   pass your athlete instance object to it, making it available to the
>   ImageUploader object instance as an instance method called 'model'.